# Asymptotic behaviour of recurrence relation

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, asymptotics

I have the following recurrence relation
$$u_0=1, u_1=5$$
$$n^3u_n-(34n^3-51n^2+27n-5)u_{n-1}+(n-1)^3u_{n-2}=0, \forall n \geq 2$$
for which I know that
$$b_n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2\binom{n+k}{k}^2$$
is the solution.

How can I prove that there exists a positive constant $A$ such that $b_n \sim A \alpha^n n^{-3/2}$
where $\alpha$ is the greatest root of the polynomial $x^2-34x+1$?

Comment: Where did you find this problem? Where is the recurrence from?

Comment: It's from a paper of Cohen about Apéry's proof of the irrationality of $\zeta(3)$. This is the link to the paper, where it is stated at the end of page 5: http://www.numdam.org/article/STNG_1977-1978__6__A6_0.pdf

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Do you have any idea?

Comment: One can show that the dominant balance method gives the asymptotic expansion (up to the multiplicative constant $A$). If $u(n) = \alpha^n n^p$, equating the leading-order term in the recurrence relation to zero gives $\alpha$. Equating the next-order term to zero gives $p$. The subsequent terms in the expansion of $u(n)$ can be obtained in this way as well. To find $A$, one can use [this method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3288328) (with $k = \beta n$).

Comment: @Maxim Could you elaborate your replay in an answer in more detail please.I don't understand how and why the method you stated work (I looked it . I think it is not really necessary for the proof I'm interested to find $A$ explicitely, just knowing it is positive should be enough. I would really, appreciate it, I've been working in understanding in full detail the proof of the paper I linked before for almost a month and this is one of the last points I don't really get. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not sure which of the two methods you refer to and what you're having difficulty with. For the dominant balance method, can you find the leading term after substituting $u = \alpha^n n^p$ into the recurrence relation? For Laplace's method, can you find the leading term in the expansion of
$$\binom n {\beta n}^2 \binom {n + \beta n} {\beta n}^2$$
with fixed $\beta \in (0, 1)$ and $n \to \infty$?

Comment: @Maxim I don't know how to find any of the two terms you say. I thought the question was easier based on Cohen saying it was easy to solve. I don't know much about asymptotic expansions, that's why I would really appreciate if you could answer in full detail, explaining how to find this terms you mention and how they are related with the limit, and maybe give some references to undertand everything better. I would really appreciate it so much. I can make a bounty and give you 100 points if you want.

Comment: @Maxim Just to be clear, the "dominant balance method" only allows to find the exact asymptotic under the assumption it has the required form (here $\alpha^n n^p$), does it not ? It does not constitute proof.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy It can be proved that if we take $u = \alpha^n n^p \sum_{k \geq 0} c_k n^{-k}$ and find $\alpha, p, c_k$ by equating the coefficients, then the result will indeed be a complete asymptotic series for the solution. We've just guessed the form of the expansion, but we do not need to make any assumptions to prove this result.

Comment: @Maxim You say "It can proved ..." How, where ? Is it hard ? I presume the $c_k$ coefficients are messy to write out (you probably don't get a closed form, just a recursive definition) and convergence of the series is not obvious.

Comment: @Maxim One thing that makes me think you're wrong is that the linked paper claims that $A=(1+\sqrt{2})^2(2\pi)^{-\frac{3}{2}}$. There's no way your method will introduce the number $\pi$ somewhere ; with your method, each $c_k$ is a rational function of $\alpha$ with integer coefficients.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy It's an asymptotic series, not necessarily convergent. Equating the coefficients doesn't fix $c_0$, so that will be the multiplicative constant not determined by the first method. I'll see if I can find a reference. There is a discussion of a rigorous justification of dominant balance in Bender and Orszag.

Comment: @Maxim Could you please develop all the knowledge and the solution to my question in a full answer? It would be helpful and I could state my doubts there after I've seen how it done and why it works. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below uses some special function theory to prove
$$ u_n:=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2\binom{n+k}{k}^2 \sim A\, (n+1/2)^{-3/2}\Big(17+12\sqrt{2}\Big)^n $$ 
where $A=(2\,\sqrt{2}\,\pi)^{-3/2}(3+2\,\sqrt{2})$ and $17+12\sqrt{2}$ is
indeed the larger root of the polynomial $x^2 - 34\,x + 1=0$, as stated in the problem.

Start with the Legendre polynomial expression 
$$ P_n(1+2x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \binom{n+k}{k} x^k $$
Use the Hadamard product (I prove it in MSE 3526636) to get
$$u_n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} P_n(1+2e^{i\,\theta}) P_n(1+2e^{-i\,\theta})\, d\theta$$ 
Now use the integral relationship for a product of Legendre polynomials
$$P_n(z)\,P_n(w) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi P_n(z\,w + \sqrt{(1-z^2)(1-w^2)}\,\cos(\phi) )\, d\phi $$
Insert this integral into the penultimate equation, do some algebra, and use a symmetry argument for the outer integral to conclude
$$ u_n = \frac{1}{\pi^2} \int_0^\pi d\theta \int_0^\pi d\phi \, P_n(5+4 \, \cos{\theta}+8\cos{(\theta/2)}\,\cos{\phi} ) $$
This double integral is that which will have performed on it asymptotic analysis.  Note that the argument of the $P_n(\cdot)$ is $\ge$ 1.  Thus the well-known asymptotic expansion next should be used.
$$ P_n(\cosh{t}) \sim \Big(\frac{t}{\sinh(t)}\Big)^{1/2} I_0\big((n+1/2)t\big)$$
For our problem, $t=\cosh^{-1}(5+4 \, \cos{\theta}+8\cos{\theta}\,\cos{\phi})$ (the inverse hyperbolic cosine).

$I_0\big(z\big)$ is the modified Bessel function and has for real positive argument the asymptotic expansion (first term only)
$$ I_0\big(z\big) \sim \frac{ \exp{(z)} }{\sqrt{2 \pi z}}\,. $$

This expansion is very useful. Looking at plots, it appears that the integrand (over $\theta$) is peaked at the origin.  As with many asymptotic problems, you'd like to get an integrand that looks like a gaussian, get the amplitude and width of the gaussian, extend the limits from a finite range ($\pi$ in our case) to $\infty$ so that an analytic result can be obtained.  That's exactly the strategy, but in 2D.

The factor raised to the 1/2 power in the penultimate equation is slowly varying, so we bring it outside the integrals, but evaluate it $\theta=0$ and $\phi=0$ (in big $\big(\cdot\big)$ below).

Thus,
$$ u_n \sim \frac{1}{\pi^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(n+1/2)}}\big( \frac{2^{-5/4}}{\sqrt{3}}\big) \cdot $$
$$ \cdot  \int_0^\pi d\theta \int_0^\pi d\phi \,
\exp{\big((n+1/2)\cosh^{-1}(5+4\,\cos{\theta} + 8\cos{(\theta/2)} \cos{\phi} )\big) } $$
Expand the argument of the exponential to order $\theta^2$ and $\phi^2.$  Extend the limits of the integrals to $\infty.$ Do the integrals explicitly.  One finds that
$$u_n \sim \frac{2^{-7/4}}{\sqrt{3(n+1/2)}\pi^{5/2}} \int_0^\infty d\theta \int_0^\infty d\phi \cdot$$
$$\cdot \exp{\big( (n+1/2)(\cosh^{-1}(17) - \frac{ \phi^2}{3\sqrt{2}} 
 - \frac{ \theta^2}{4\sqrt{2}}-5\frac{\theta^2 \phi^2 }{288 \sqrt{2} }  \big)}
$$
$$ = \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}\frac{\exp{\big( (n+1/2)(\cosh^{-1}(17) 
+ 6\sqrt{2}/5 ) \big)}}{2 \pi^2 (n+1/2)} K_0\big( (n+1/2)6\sqrt{2}/5 \big) $$
where $K_0(\cdot)$ is the Macdonald function.

Use the asymptotic formula 
$$ K_0\big(z) \sim e^{-z}\sqrt{ \frac{\pi}{2z} } .$$
Algebra (including hyperboic trig ID's) completes the proof.

That the Legendre polynomials are used is actually quite natural.  One proof of
the irrationality of $\zeta(3)$ uses them explicitly.

For comparison: with $n=30$, the difference between the sum and its asymptotic approximation is about 1%.  For $n=301,$ about 0.1%.

Comment: Hi, it seems that you know a lot about asymptotics, could you recomend me some books where it is discussed in detail all the special functions and expansions you mention, please? Thank you.

Comment: @Eparoh The 2nd equation is shown in the wikipedia article under 'Rodrigues' formula...' Same article, 'asymptotes' gives the expansion for argument< 1; to have an argument > 1, you let $\theta \to i \theta.$  (This is from memory however, and must be justified, and I can't recall a good reference presently.)  The Bessel K function asymptotics is standard stuff, such as might be found in the back of Gradshteyn and Ryzhik.  The proof is a grab bag of things (I wasn't taught about a Hadamard product in my physics courses), so I doubt there is an ideal single source to get more detail.