# Limit of Hypergeometric function

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation, hypergeometric-function

I am trying to compute a limit of a sum, and Mathematica can only write the sum as a Hypergeometric function, but it cannot compute the limit. So I have:

$$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{ {2N \choose N }}  \sum_{k=0}^N {N \choose k}^2 \, \left[ \frac{(1+z/N)(1+w/N)}{(1+u/N)(1+v/N)} \right]^k = \\
= \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{ {2N \choose N }} \; \ _2F_1 \left(-N, -N, 1, \frac{(1+z/N)(1+w/N)}{(1+u/N) (1+v/N)} \right)$$

where $z$, $w$, $u$ and $v$ are complex numbers. Any ideas on how to take the limit, using some trick on the summation or some properties of the Hypergeometric function?

Comment: Are $n$ and $N$ the same thing?

Comment: Yes, sorry, edited

Comment: Your Hypergeometric function is a terminating sum exactly the same as your sum from $k=0$ to $N$.

Comment: It may help that $$
(x - 1)^N P_N \left( {\frac{{x + 1}}{{x - 1}}} \right) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^N {\binom{N}{k}^2 x^k } ,
$$ where $P_N$ is the $N$th Legendre polynomial.

Comment: @Somos yes it is a sum from $k=0$ to $N$, and I am taking the limit $N \rightarrow \infty$. What do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean that the terminating Hypergeometric function on the right side is by definition a sum of terms that is identical to your sum on the left side of the equation. That is, not only are the sums equal, but every corresponding term in the two sums are equal

Comment: Apply [this method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3288328). If $k = \alpha N$, the maximum of the exponential part is at $\alpha = \sqrt x/(1 + \sqrt x)$. We'll have
$${_2 F_1}(-N, -N; 1; x) \sim
\frac {(\sqrt x + 1)^{2 N + 1}} {2 \sqrt {\pi N} x^{1/4}},$$
which still holds for $x = (N + z) (N + w)/((N + u) (N + v))$. The limit is $e^{(z + w - u - v)/2}$.