# Asymptotic form of hypergeometric function ${}_1 F_1(a,b,z)$ at large $a,z$.

Tags: asymptotics, hypergeometric-function

I am looking for the asymptotic form of the hypergeometric function ${}_1 F_1 (a,b,z)$
in the limit $a,z\rightarrow\infty$ with $a/z\rightarrow \mathrm{const}$, and $b\geq 1$.

Specifically, I am interested in the case where $a=1,2,\dots$ is a positive integer, $b$ is a small positive integer (mostly interested in $b=1$ or $b=2$), and $z=\alpha(2a-1)$ for some real positive constant $\alpha$, in the limit $a\rightarrow\infty$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Apply [this method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3288328). If $k = \lambda a$, the maximum will be at $\lambda_0 = \alpha + \sqrt {\alpha^2 + 2 \alpha}$. Then
$${_1 \hspace {-1 px} F_1}(a; b; \alpha (2 a - 1)) \sim
\frac
  {\left( \frac \alpha {\alpha + 2} \right)^{\hspace {-2 px} 1/4} \Gamma(b)}
  {\lambda_0^b \sqrt {2 \pi e^{\lambda_0}}}
 a^{1/2 - b} ((\lambda_0 + 1) e^{\lambda_0})^a,
\quad a \to \infty.$$

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks!