# A limit involving the hypergeometric function

Tags: limits, hypergeometric-function

I'm trying to evaluate the following (discrete) limit:

$$ \lim_{k \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{_2 F_1(-k,ky,ky+1,-t^{1/k})}{2^k} $$
where $y>0$ and $t>0$ are some fixed real numbers. My idea was to use some transformation for the hypergeometric function which may lead to something easier to calculate, or maybe (if the first argument of $_2 F_1$ becomes a number which is not a negative integer) where the limit can be interchanged with the infinite sum via Tannery's Theorem. However, I have not been able to find any transformation which can be used to do this. Does anybody know how to evaluate this limit?

Comment: Apply [this method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3288328) to
$$\sum_{i \geq 0} \frac {(k - i + 1)_i (y k)_i} {(y k + 1)_i}
 \frac {t^{i/k}} {i!}$$
(with $i = \alpha k$, the maximum will be at $\alpha = 1/2$). The limit is $2 y \sqrt t/(2 y + 1)$.

Comment: Thank you very much!