# How to see this approximation for hypergeometric function?

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I came across this formula in a [physics paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.4641.pdf)(equation 2.28). For  $k \gg \omega$, it was stated that the following is true:

${}_2 F_1\hspace{-4pt}\left[\frac{\Delta+i (k+\omega)}{2},
    \frac{\Delta-i (k-\omega)}{2}
    ; \Delta ; x^2\right] \sim e^{[k \sin^{-1} x]}$
where $_2 F_1$ is the ordinary or Gausssian [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).

Here $\Delta$ is a positive real number and $k,x$ are real as well. $i$ is the imaginary square root of -1. I don't see how this follows. Any help in arriving at this formula would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you need the definition of $F$. And could you give a link to the paper?

Comment: Is $i$ the imaginary number ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes, it is.

Comment: @mrsamy added the link to the paper.

Comment: This identity may help you
$$
F\left(-a,a;\frac{1}{2};\sin^2z\right)=\cos\left(2az\right).
$$
see https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.4

Comment: Assume that $\Delta > 0$, $\omega \in \mathbb R$ and $0 < x <1$. The real and imaginary parts of the terms of the hypergeometric series form unimodal sequences, so [this method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3288328) is applicable (but will require some calculations if you want to get an asymptotic equivalence rather than just show divergence):
$${_2 F_1} \sim
 \frac {2^{\Delta - 3/2} \Gamma(\Delta) }
  {(1 - x^2)^{1/4 + i \omega/2} \sqrt \pi}
 (k x)^{1/2 - \Delta} e^{k \arcsin x},
\quad k \to \infty.$$