# Specific values or asymptotic behaviour of ${}_{1}F_{1}$

Tags: asymptotics, hypergeometric-function

I'm interested in analysing the behaviour of the hypergeometric function ${}_{1}F_{1}$ for the following cases:
$${}_{1}F_{1}\Big[\frac{1}{2} - \frac{k}{2}, \frac{1}{2}; -z^2\Big]$$
and
$${}_{1}F_{1}\Big[1 - \frac{k}{2}, \frac{3}{2}; -z^2\Big]$$
for integer values, $k \in \mathbf{N}$. So far I've used some properties I found on [NIST](https://dlmf.nist.gov/13) for small values of $k$ and uncovered error functions.

Can these functions be simplified more generally for this special case of integer or half-integer first arguments -- even getting some asymptotic form as $k \rightarrow \infty$ would be very welcome information!

EDIT:

It seems that I can use the identities
$$\begin{align}
{}_{1}F_{1}\Big[\frac{1}{2} - \frac{k}{2}, \frac{1}{2}; -z^2\Big] &= \textrm{e}^{-z^2}{}_{1}F_{1}\Big[\frac{k}{2}, \frac{1}{2}; z^2\Big]\\
{}_{1}F_{1}\Big[1 - \frac{k}{2}, \frac{3}{2}; -z^2\Big] &= \textrm{e}^{-z^2}{}_{1}F_{1}\Big[\frac{k}{2}+\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2}; z^2\Big]
\end{align}
$$
to change sign of the first argument - does this help uncover any additional properties I can use?
Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: For even $k$ it's a polynomial of degree $k−2$, related to Laguerre polynomials.

Comment: Well, it looks like you have the Hermite function $h_\lambda(x)={}_1F_1(-\lambda/2,1/2;x^2)$ with a sign difference.

Comment: The only reference I've found connecting these functions to Laguerre polynomials also contains awkward error functions - is there a relationship without these?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials#Relation_to_hypergeometric_functions

Comment: Apply [this method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3288328) to
$$F = \sum_{j \geq 0} \frac {(n + a)_j} {(b)_j} \frac {x^j} {j!}.$$
If $j = \alpha \sqrt n$, the summand is asymptotic to $f(\alpha) e^{\phi(\alpha) \sqrt n}$ with
$$f(\alpha) = \frac {\Gamma(b) e^{\alpha^2/2}} {2 \pi \alpha^b n^{b/2}}, \\
\phi(\alpha) = \alpha (\ln x - 2 \ln \alpha + 2).$$
It suffices to approximate the sum for values of $\alpha$ close to $\sqrt x$, which gives
$$F \sim \sqrt n f(\sqrt x) \int_{\mathbb R}
 e^{(\phi(\sqrt x) + \phi''(\sqrt x) \alpha^2/2) \sqrt n} d\alpha,
\quad n \to \infty.$$

Comment: Great suggestion - thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By http://dlmf.nist.gov/13.6.iv, we have
$$
e{}^{ - z^2 }\!{}_1F_1 \!\left( {\frac{k}{2},\frac{1}{2};z^2 } \right) \!= \frac{{2^{\frac{k}{2} - 1} }}{{\sqrt \pi  }}\Gamma\! \left( {\frac{{k + 1}}{2}} \right)\!e^{ - \frac{{z^2 }}{2}} \!\!\left( {U\!\left( {k - \frac{1}{2},\sqrt 2 z} \right) \!+ U\!\left( {k - \frac{1}{2}, - \sqrt 2 z} \right)} \right)
$$
and
$$
e{}^{ - z^2 }\!{}_1F_1 \!\left( {\frac{{k + 1}}{2},\frac{3}{2};z^2 } \right) \!= \frac{{2^{\frac{k}{2} - 2} }}{{z\sqrt {\pi } }}\Gamma\! \left( {\frac{k}{2}} \right)\!e^{ - \frac{{z^2 }}{2}} \!\!\left( {U\!\left( {k - \frac{1}{2}, - \sqrt 2 z} \right) \!- U\!\left( {k - \frac{1}{2},\sqrt 2 z} \right)} \right)\!.
$$
The parabolic cylinder functions then may be expressed in terms of the derivatives of the complementary error function (cf. http://dlmf.nist.gov/12.7.E6). There is probably no simpler "explicit" expression for these functions.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for - certainly each function in these expressions admits an easy asymptotic expansion